# add button in UITextfield iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uitextfield, addition

add button in UITextfield iphone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 120, 160, 40)];
    txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txt.placeholder = @"enter name";
    [txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_chapter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    txt.rightView = button;
    txt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}

-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you want to add a button inside UITextField?

If my guess is right, I think you can just add a button 'on' UITextField.

No need to put 'in' UITextField.